# Combining two tables with a different column

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, plsql, union

I have to select requests that i want to combine using UNION :

**Table 1** : which is a join between Table_a, table_b and table_c

```
id_table_a   desc_table_a   table_b.id_user  table_c.field
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            desc1            1                 field1
2            desc2            2                 field2
3            desc3            3                 field3
```

**Table 2** : which is also a join between Table_a, table_b and table_c but it has these columns:

```
id_table_a   desc_table_a   table_c.id_user  table_c.field
-----------------------------------------------------------
4            desc4            4                 field4
5            desc5            5                 field8
9            desc9            6                 field9
```

the difference between the two is that in Table1 we have `table_b.id_user` and table two 
`table_c.id_user` instead .

Combined Table

```
  id_table_a   desc_table_a     id_user  table_c.field
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1            desc1            1                 field1
    2            desc2            2                 field2
    3            desc3            3                 field3
    4            desc4            4                 field4
    5            desc5            5                 field5
    9            desc9            6                 field6
```

I already have the join requests working but doing union between the two gives me

```
ORA-01790 expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

which make sense because the two columns are not the same .

Im using zend_Db's join and union for this .

So how can i tackle this to get the result ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the datatypes of all your fields in the used queries? What was your query?

Comment: Table 1 and Table 2 fields have exactly the same datatypes, id_user in both table_b and table_c have same type in DB (NUMBER(6,0))

Comment: Well, ORA-01790 only happens when they are not (see e.g. here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01790.php )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are the results above the same as the sequence of columns in your table? because oracle is strict in column orders. this example below produces an error:

```
create table test1_1790 (
col_a varchar2(30),
col_b number,
col_c date);

create table test2_1790 (
col_a varchar2(30),
col_c date,
col_b number);

select * from test1_1790
union all
select * from test2_1790;
```

**ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression**

As you see the root cause of the error is in the mismatching column ordering that is implied by the use of * as column list specifier. This type of errors can be easily avoided by entering the column list explicitly:

```
select col_a, col_b, col_c from test1_1790
union all
select col_a, col_b, col_c from test2_1790;
```

A more frequent scenario for this error is when you inadvertently swap (or shift) two or more columns in the SELECT list:

```
select col_a, col_b, col_c from test1_1790
union all
select col_a, col_c, col_b from test2_1790;
```

**OR if the above does not solve your problem, how about creating an** `ALIAS` **in the columns**
like this: (the query is not the same as yours but the point here is how to add alias in the column.)

```
SELECT id_table_a, 
       desc_table_a, 
       table_b.id_user as iUserID, 
       table_c.field as iField
UNION
SELECT id_table_a, 
       desc_table_a, 
       table_c.id_user as iUserID, 
       table_c.field as iField
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot , did both suggestions and it works like a charm :)